# Reinstallation of Freya

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

So I was a bit skeptical about elementary OS, but after 2 weeks I am converted. I came from Slackware back in the days, onto Ubuntu and now elementary OS. Thanks to the team.

So in the two weeks I have installed many other apps, but now running into some issues. I want to do a reinstall without having to go through the installation process. Is there an easy way to do a reinstall?

Comment: are you asking to reinstall?.."installation process" means?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a "easy way" to put the elementary OS in a "clean" state, with only the default packages installed.

Well, you can try use the packages managers like Synaptic or Aptitude, or even the `apt-get`, to uninstall ALL packages and then reinstall the package `elementary-desktop` and its dependecies. But there's no safety nets there, you may accidentally forget to reinstall important packages and turn your elementary inaccessible.

The easiest (and maybe fastest) way is backup your data and do a fresh install.