# How do I if possible, master reset?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal, appcenter

I don't know what I did but the app center no longer works. When I try to install something it says waiting and then install comes back up. Also in the terminal whenever I type in a Audi command it says that it's unknown.

Comment: What do you mean by an Audi command?

Comment: I understand from your question that you're looking for some kind of reinstallation keeping your data. There's an answer from @ThiagoJedi that, thought refering to "Freya" should be considered valid also for "Loki": http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2553/6398

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal, it worked for me at least.